# display of a single linked list is not as expected

Tags: c, linked-list

this code is working perfectly but there is a problem in some line, as a result i am getting output like this

enter the no of nodes
5
enter the elements to the list
1
2
3
4
5
the elements are
1 1 2 3 4 5
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 5.956 s
Press any key to continue.

problem - as you can see the first element is printed twice.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void create(int a[],int n)
{
int i;
struct node *x,*far;
first=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
first->data=a[0];
first->next=NULL;
far=first;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    x=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    x->data=a[i];
    x->next=NULL;
    far->next=x;  //connects the node far to x
    far=x;  //shifts the node far to x now far will be pointing to x
}
}

void display(struct node *p)
{
while(p!=NULL)
{
    printf("%d ",p->data);
    p=p->next;
}
}

int main()
{
int a[10],n=0,i;
printf("enter the no of nodes\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("enter the elements to the list\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);

create(a,n);
printf("the elements are\n");
display(first);
}
```

Comment: The code is not working. Your display function looks OK. Your create function is creating a list with n + 1 nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written function `create()` in a bad way (`for` loop to be more detailed).

You should write it in this way:

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    struct node *x= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    x->data=a[i];
    x->next=NULL;
    far->next=x;  //connects the node far to x
    far=x;  //shifts the node far to x now far will be pointing to x
}
```

(you must start counting from 1, because zeroth element is already initialized and filled)

Additional protip: you can remove pointer casts near `malloc()` function calls, because C allows to implicitly convert `void *` to another pointer types.

You should also add `free()` calls to release memory occupied by your list at the end of `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the first element of the array into the list here

```
first->data=a[0];
```

and here when initially `i` is 0

```
x->data=a[i];
```

You can stop that by starting the loop at 1

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) /* to be changed to */
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
```